# Generating code coverage report using theIntern

Tags: code-coverage, intern

I am using theIntern for unit testing my javascript framework. My test is running fine using node.

However, I am not able to generate code coverage report properly. I tried the options provided in the documentation. I was successful to print code coverage information on to the console while testing through selenium web driver.  That gives only a summary.

How can I generate extensive code coverage report using reporters other than console?

I provided the "reporters" option but doesn't print the report. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `lcov` reporter generates an `lcov.info` file that can then be passed to the lcov [`genhtml`](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/genhtml.1.php) utility to output a complete set of HTML coverage reports (the simplest invocation is just `genhtml lcov.info`).

In Intern 1.2, however, there is a [bug with the generated lcov.info files](https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/95) (fixed for Intern 1.3) that may cause `genhtml` to fail to find any coverage data inside a generated `lcov.info` file. The [patch for this issue](https://github.com/theintern/intern/commit/85baf23ecaba8af74581cd7b63c00efc43e20746) is very simple and you should be able to cleanly it to Intern 1.2 until the new version is released in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like genhtml is more for Linux. Should I use JGentHtml if I have to use in windows environment? 

On a broader note, how can I automate all these steps of running the unittest and generating code coverage? Is there any maven plugin that can do all these?